Question regarding equivalent statements for solvable, finite groups
Definition (Solvable): $G$ is solvable if there exists $G_0,G_1, \cdots G_r$ so that $$1=G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft G_2 \cdots \triangleleft G_r=G $$ such that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is Abelian for $i \leq r-1$.
Theorem: If $G$ is finite, the following are equivalent:

$G$ is solvable
$G$ has a series $1=H_0 \triangleleft H_1 \cdots \triangleleft H_l=G $ so that $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is cyclic
$G$ has a series $1=N_0 \triangleleft N_1 \cdots \triangleleft N_r=G$ so that $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is Abelian, and also $N_i$ is normal in $G$ for each $i$.

I was able to show that $(1) \iff (2)$ and $(3) \implies (1)$ (This is obvious).
Where I have a problem is $(3) \implies (1) $ (or (2)).

My idea was to apply induction in the following manner: For group of order 1, they are readily solvable, and (3) is also trivially true. I then assume that for any group that is solvable, whose order is smaller than that of $G$, (3) is true. Now I take $G$, which is said to be solvable. I write out the solvable series of $G$,
$$1=G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft G_2 \cdots \triangleleft G_r=G $$ such that $G_{i+1}/G_{i}$ is Abelian (by (b), it must also be cyclic). I take $G_{r-1}$ and apply induction hypothesis to this:
There exists $H_0,H_1 \cdots H_p$ so that $1=H_0 \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft H_2 \cdots \triangleleft H_p=G_{r-1}$ such that $H_{i+1}/H_{i}$ is Abelian, but also $H_i$ for each $i$ is normal to $H_p$. Another information is that $G/H_{p}=G/G_{r-1}$ is cyclic. If I can show that $H_i \triangleleft G$ we are done.
How do I do this?

Hint for $1\implies 3$: Consider the derived series of the group.

@Mark I am not aware of the derived series. I am solving Dummit and Foote, in which this comes up in the 3rd chapter concerning homomorphisms and quotients

See this post, and similar ones here at this site. Most of the proofs given there follow the book by Dummit and Foote.

The statement of the theorem is wrong. In 2 and 3 you don't mean a composition series, you mean a subnormal series A composition series is defined to be a subnormal series in which each factor $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is simple.

@DerekHolt you are correct, I have edited the question. I was using the term composition series for any sequence of increasing normal groups, while the actual meaning is the specific Jordan Holder series. I've changed that now.

Lemma: If $M \triangleleft G$ is the minimal non trivial normal subgroup of $G$, then $M $ must be Abelian.
Proof: Let $M$ be as hypothesis and $N \triangleleft M$ be a normal subgroup of $M$.
Note that, since $G$ is solvable, all the composition factors are prime order (to see this, consider any composition series of $G$, $1=G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \cdots G_{r-1} \triangleleft G_r=G$ so that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is simple. Take the claim itself as induction hypothesis. Since $G_{r-1}$ is also solvable, we apply the claim to $G_{r-1}$ that all of its composition factors are prime order. Then we look at $G/G_{r-1}$ which is also solvable. But note that $G/G_{r-1}$ is also simple. So its solvable series (that series whose factors are abelian) contains only itself and 1, which makes $G/G_{r-1}$ abelian. From Abelian Cauchy theorem, we find that $G/G_{r-1}$ has to be prime order. This concludes that every composition factor of $G$ must be prime order.)
If we suppose that $N \triangleleft M$ is the maximal normal subgroup of $M$ (that is not itself $M$) then we can say that $M/N$ is simple. Hence there is a composition series of $G$ with $N$ and $M$. Hence $M/N$ is of prime order, and looks like $(eN, xN, x^2N, \cdots x^{p-1}N)$.
Let $a,b \in M$. Since cosets of $N$ split the set $M$, every element in $M$ is of the form $x^j n$ for some $j$ and some $n \in N$. $a=x^{j_a}n_a$ and $b=x^{j_b}n_b$. $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=(x^{j_a}n_ax^{j_b}n_b)(n_a^{-1}x^{-j_a}n_b^{-1}x^{-j_b})$. With some algebra, we can see that $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in N$. Moreover, the set $gNg^{-1}:=\{gng^{-1}:n \in N\}$ also is normal in $M$ and by a similar argument, $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in gNg^{-1}$. Therefore we have that for all $a,b \in M$, $$aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in K= \cap_{g \in G} gNg^{-1}$$ Note that $K$ is normal in $G$, and is contained in $N$. Since $M$ is the minimal, nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ $K$ must be trivial and $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$. Hence, $M $ is Abelian.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Now suppose that $G$ is solvable, and that for all solvable groups whose size is smaller than $G$, (4) is true. Consider $M$, the minimal normal subgroup of $G$. We take a look at $G/M$ which is a solvable group, and hence here too induction hypothesis can be applied. Therefore, we have $1=K_{0}/M \triangleleft K_{1}/M \cdots \triangleleft K_{r-1}/M \triangleleft K_{r}/M=G/M$ such that $(K_{i+1}/M)/(K_{i}/M) \cong K_{i+1}/K_{i}$ are abelian, and $K_{i+1}/M$ is normal in $G/M$ which makes $K_{i+1}$ normal in $G$, too.
Therefore, all in all we have $$1=I \triangleleft M= K_0 \triangleleft K_1 \cdots \triangleleft K_{r-1} \triangleleft K_r=G $$ such that $M/I$ is abelian, $M$ is normal in G, $K_{i+1}/K_i$ is abelian and $K_i$ are all normal in $G$. Hence, (4) is established for $G$.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
